# Is it possible to disable or reassign the built in Windows keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts

Is it possible to disable or reassign some or all of the built in Windows keyboard shortcuts?  Are there any third party tools that make this task easy?  Has the method to accomplish this task changed between Windows releases?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to set a registry entry for disabling hotkeys involving the "Windows" key.

Disable for All Users:

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer`

Disable for YOUR User:

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Exlporer`

- You may have to add the "Explorer" key to your CURRENT_USER.

Add a new DWORD (32-bit) Value named **NoWinKeys**

Set the value to "1" to disable and "0" to enable.

Comment: This solution would only disable the shortcuts, not re-map them.

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest this here:
[AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/)

AutoHotkey unleashes the full potential of your keyboard, joystick, and mouse. For example, in addition to the typical Control, Alt, and Shift modifiers, you can use the Windows key and the Capslock key as modifiers. In fact, you can make any key or mouse button act as a modifier.

Also see [here](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/HotkeyFeatures.htm)